# How to extract bigger volumes of data from sites using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an idea how to extract links and other data from sites using BeautifulSoup. For instance, I extract all links from this site https://finance.yahoo.com/. However, it provides me with a very limited set of links (articles from today or just very recent), while I would like to have links to articles for about a monthly period. I mean, for instance, get all the links starting from the 1st of January.

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    url0 = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/'
    page0 = requests.get(url0)
    soup0=BeautifulSoup(page0.text, 'lxml')
    urls=[]
    for link in soup0.find_all('a'):
      if '/news' in link.get('href'):
      urls.append(link.get('href'))       
    full_urls=['https://finance.yahoo.com' + u for u in urls]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share the code you have worked out so far.

Comment: There is not much code as i am stuck with this problem and right now there is not much to do with the data i have. I added the code however